# Will changing hostname in OpenBSD affect installed packages?

Tags: openbsd, hostname

With regards to OpenBSD 5.6, suppose I change my hostname in /etc/myname

1. Will doing so affect installed packages, root password or user's passwords?
2. Do I have to reboot my machine after changing my hostname?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the entry in /etc/myname and everything else will still work as usual. The new hostname you put in /etc/myname won't take effect until you reboot though.  From the man page for myname:

```
 The myname and mygate files are read by netstart(8) at system startup
 time.

 /etc/myname contains the symbolic name of the host machine.  The file
 should contain a single line specifying the fully qualified domain name
 (FQDN) of the system (e.g. host.example.com).  The name must be
 resolvable, either by matching a hostname specified in /etc/hosts (see
 hosts(5)) or through DNS (see resolv.conf(5)).  The hostname is set via
 the hostname(1) utility at boot time.  See hostname(7) for a description
 of hostname resolution.
```